# Configuration of graph for maxcut algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, quantum-computation

I am attempting to run a [maxcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) quantum algorithm with qiskit-aqua. I am trying to create a configuration of a graph of n number of nodes. These nodes are random values of a single parameter.

For eg.

[image: deterministic graph]

Created by the edge list of:

```
[(0,1,1.0),(0,2,1.0),(0,3,1.0),(0,4,1.0),(0,5,1.0),(0,6,1.0),(0,7,1.0),(0,8,1.0),(0,9,1.0)]
```

Where the values are:

```
(vertex1, vertex2, weight)
```

The graph shown deterministically results in the vertex in the middle of the graph being in a group on its own, which is not what I am after. The solution needs to be a single random node.

Does a graph configuration exist such that a max cut would always result in 2 groups, with one group always containing a random single vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this is the only case:

[image]

Comment: Disappointing! That makes sense now of course... I will have to use a different algorithm to generate a single non-deterministic value from the set. Thank-you for confirming this was not the way to go!